# objective-c: Inconsistency in nil detection

Tags: objective-c, ios

The following code generates an inconsistent output.  It is supposed to log "testString is nil : (null)".  But it sometimes also logs "testString is : (null)".

What can caused this or did I miss something?

```
NSString *testString = nil;
if (!testString)
    NSLog(@"testString is nil : %@", testString);
else
    NSLog(@"testString is : %@", testString);
```

Comment: "_sometimes_" is the problem here. When exactly? This code as is might even loose the else part in optimization.

Comment: surely "testString is (null)" is not possible here no matter what testString is, maybe "testString is : (null)"?

Comment: testString is probably @"(null)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your test string is coming from, eg, a stringWithFormat operation such as `stringWithFormat:@"%@", someObject`, and "someObject" is nil.

Comment: this guy is awesome, I'd never think in this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this isn't the exact code you're running?

At a guess, maybe your variable ended up containing `[NSNull null]`.

Comment: No, that would log as `<null>` rather than `(null)`.

Comment: Maybe his test string contains "(null)".

Comment: DRH: is there different between testing (testString == nil) and [testString isEqualToString:@"(null)"?

Comment: @user: Yes, in the first case there is not a valid object at `testString`, and in the second, there is a string whose characters are `(null)`. When you `NSLog(@"%@", nil);`, it prints `(null)` to indicate there is no object. If you did `NSLog(@"%@", @"(null)");`, it would look exactly the same, but would obviously not mean the same thing.